# iOS FrameWork UnitTesting

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

I have created a iOS framework and want to use that framework in one of my application.

My question is about the UnitTesting of the framework. 
I have read about the inbuilt xcode unittest framework, but not sure how to get started on testing the framework.

Or do I have to import the framework in one of my apps and then perform the testing of the framework via

Regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new target to your project, select Others -> Cocoa Touch Unit Testing Bundle, give it a name.

Add to the new target the Compile Sources and the Link Binary. And in your test class write the tests you need.

Comment: Thanks. I added the target and added the Compile Sources (MYFrameworkTest.m) and Link Binary (My Frameworks outputfile .framework). When I build and use "Product -> Test"after a while it says test completed and No Issues. And in the testExample function I have written STFAil macro and some other STAssertFalse macros. But it seems it is not hitting that code. Any pointers ?